# Restored deleted project in NetBeans won't load

Tags: java, netbeans, project

I have already tried every tip here but still can not load my deleted project.
I used `EaseUS` data recovery to restore whole directory but my main class and everything else is missing [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3nVa.png) . Also when I try to build the project I get `\build.xml:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.`

I have searched everywhere but still can't find solution. Help please!

Comment: More information is needed: [1] Post the content of **build.xml**. [2] Select your restored project in the **Files** panel, expand its tree structure to show the major files and directories, and update your question with a screen shot of that.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. There was nothing much to work with anyways, all I had left in my project folder were libraries. However I was able to restore my `.jar` and extract the code with `JavaDecompiler`.